# Apollo Server executeOperation with authorization headers

Tags: node.js, graphql, jwt, apollo-server

How do we pass headers to Apollo server `executeOperation` in tests?

There is mention about passing a headers object [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/4337)

I'm trying to pass an auth header with or without a JWT token to test access control.

```js
const result = await server.executeOperation({ query: query, http: { headers: { authorization: "" } } })

// Type '{ authorization: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
//  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'authorization' does not exist in type 'Headers'.ts(2322)
```

This results in a type error. There is a Headers class defined in the Apollo server types in `fetch.d.ts` but I'm un able to import to instantiate it.

Using `"apollo-server": "^2.25.2"`. Any hints or links to get this going?

---

Update: as a work around I'm decrypting and decoding the JWT in the server context and passing an authenticated user around in there. Then I'm able to mock the whole context and create a new test server with the mocked context. It'd be nice to be able to user headers for more production like experience but this works for now.

```js
import { mockDeep, mockReset } from 'jest-mock-extended'

interface Context {
  prisma: PrismaClient
  user: () => User|null
}

export const context = mockDeep<Context>()

export const testServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context
});

// ...

context.user.mockReturnValue({
  id: 1,
  name: "Foo",
  slug: "foo",
})

const res = await testServer.executeOperation({ query: query })
```

Comment: docs are very thin on this. Also seeking some info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apollo Server now supports a second parameter for executeOperation. It is possible to provide the parameters used in the context function.

```
  const result = await server.executeOperation(
    { query: query },
    { req: { headers: { authorization: '...' } } }
  );
```

Note: With Typescript, it will complain but you can cast it in any and avoid building the whole `express.Request` type.

Tested with apollo-server-core@3.5.0

The other solution works but I find this one convenient. If you mock the token parsing, you can easily simulate calls from different users.

---

Comment: Thanks for the notification. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I have created a 'fake' request object with the already decrypted JWT token that I used to initialize my third party auth object (keycloak) and pass to the apollo context. I need to initialize the keycloak object because I have authentication schema directives that require the keycloak object to be initialized.

```
 const req = {
      kauth: {
        grant: {
          access_token: {
            isExpired: () => {
              return false;
            },
            token: "abc",
            content: {
              email: "me@me.com",
              resource_access: {
                "my-api": {
                  roles: ["admin"],
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };

    server = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
      resolvers,
      dataSources: () => ({
        users,
      }),
      context: () => {
        return { kauth: new KeycloakContext({ req }) };
      },
    });
  });
```

Still, I would like a solution that is more native to apollo and not a work around.