# How do I send an authorization header in apollo server execute operation?

Tags: node.js, testing, integration-testing, apollo, apollo-server

How to send authorization header with this code without having a typescript error?

```
const result = await apolloServer.executeOperation({
        query: `{ getUsers { id } }`,
})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73299622/16776416) to pass the authorization header.

For Typescript, in case it is not clear, here it is:

```
  const result = await server.executeOperation(
    { query: query },
    { req: { headers: { authorization: '...' } } } as any
  );
```