# Setting headers for JEST integration testing on Apollo

Tags: jestjs

Hi i'm facing an error in my code, this is the code.
I am not able to set the headers inside executeOperation function of Apollo as i need accessToken to run next mutation or a query.
loginToken is being set and i can retrieve it's value . But when i set headers before query "getClientConfiguration" it gives me unauthorized response because of header.

```
const { createServerWithSchema } = require('../../gql/server')

let loginToken;

describe('Space test suite', () => {
  
  it('returns login token', async () => {
    const testServer = await createServerWithSchema()

    const result = await testServer.executeOperation({
        query: `
        query loginFromEmail{
            loginFromEmail(
                email:"qa+stadiumexperiencehost@pavemint.com"
                password:"Password1"
            )
            {
                accessToken
            }
        }
    `
    })

    
    const { accessToken } = result.data.loginFromEmail
    loginToken = accessToken
    expect(result.errors).toEqual(undefined)
  })


  it('returns clientConfiguration', async () => {
    const testServer = await createServerWithSchema()

    const result = await testServer.executeOperation({
        http: {
            headers : {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${loginToken}`
            }
        },
        query: 'query getClientConfiguration { getClientConfiguration { GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY } }',
    })
    
    console.log("result", result)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For

> Setting headers for JEST integration testing on Apollo

[Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73299622/16776416).